# Как можно вычислить разницу между двумя датами php

Tags: php

Имея две даты . Например 1.01.2022 и 15.03.2022 как можно вывести количество месяцев между двумя датами ? Например - январь, февраль и март. Просто если считать в днях то получается 2 месяца. на php

Comment: покажите код, который возвращает 2 месяца. тем более, что он правильно считает. А вы хотите округление вверх?

Comment: Да все верно. Просто цель округлить даты ,если например у нас имеются неполные дни .Я понимаю что расчет ведется верно, просто хотелось бы как то найти способ округлить

Comment: код-то приложите по правилам сайта

Comment: Ну вообще было бы неплохо если бы вы приложили вашу попытку решить эту задачу, правила сообщества обязывают.

Comment: А между 31.01 и 01.03 сколько месяцев?

Comment: Спасибо ребята!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$t1 = strtotime('1.01.2022');
$t2 = strtotime('15.03.2022');
$start = ($t1 < $t2)? $t1 : $t2;//проверка какое число меньше
$end = ($t1 < $t2)? $t2 : $t1;//проверка какое число больше
$years = date('Y',$end) - date('Y',$start);
$month = ($years * 12) + date('m',$end) - date('m',$start);
echo $month;
```